# Extract the name of a method passed as an action parameter

Tags: c#, lambda, visual-studio-2019, anonymous-function

I have a main method, ExecuteMethod, in C# which is in charge of executing the method passed as a parameter. Now I would like to make a log to a file in order to know which method is being executed every time (I am only interested in getting the method name):

```
    public static void ExecuteMethod(Action myMethod)
    {
        ExecuteMethod(() => { myMethod(); return true; });
    }

    public static object ExecuteMethod(Func<object> myMethod)
    {
        string myMethodName = <method_name>; // How to extract method name here from myMethod parameter?
        MyLog.Write("Calling to " + myMethodName);

        // more stuff here
    }
```

So for example, in my program I have calls like below:

```
    public void m1()
    {
        ExecuteMethod(() => myCore.SomeMethod1(param1, param2));
    }

    public void m2()
    {
        ExecuteMethod(() => myCore.SomeMethod2(param1, param2, null));
    }
```

Then from above ExecuteMethod, I would like to obtain the names of these methods passed as parameter which would be SomeMethod1 and SomeMethod2 in this case. How can I achieve this?

Comment: [`[CallerMemberName]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: @canton7 It seems using [CallerMemberName] is returning in my case method names m1 and m2 instead of SomeMethod1 and SomeMethod2 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the `Action` properties revealed `Action.Method.Name`, but the name it reports is a run-time construct that doesn't say much. In your case it would probably report something like `<m1>b__2_0`.

You could work around this by passing the name of the method with the call to `ExecuteMethod`:

```
ExecuteMethod(() => myCore.SomeMethod1(param1, param2), nameof(myCore.SomeMethod1));
```

And using that:

```
public static object ExecuteMethod(Func<object> myMethod, string methodName)
{        
    MyLog.Write("Calling to " + methodName);

    // more stuff here
}
```